# Insert error message in new line after current

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validate and I'm trying to place the error message below the current element. My form is in list-style (li). I have tried several solutions I've found here on Stackoverflow but it has not worked for my code. One problem is perhaps my time (tid) input because I have four inputs in one li.

HTML:

```
<li><label>Datum *<br> <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker"></label></li>
<li>
                <label>Tid: från-till *<br> 
                <input type="text" name="time" id="time" maxlength="2" size="2"></label>:
                <input type="text" name="time" id="time" maxlength="2" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<!--Extra space-->
                <input type="text" name="time" id="time" maxlength="2" size="2">:
                <input type="text" name="time" id="time" maxlength="2" size="2">
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        //error.insertAfter(element);
         //error.appendTo( element.parent("li").next("li") );
         //$(element).after('<li>'+error.text()+'</li>');
         $(element).append('<li>' + error.text() + '</li>');
    } // end errorPlacement
```

Is there and errorplacement solution for my current HTML-code or should I change the html code some how? I chose this way with multiple input types inside one li to make it harder for the user to input wrong data and to make it easier for me to handle it.

Comment: You cannot have four `type="text"` elements with the same `name` and `id`. Duplication of `id` is invalid HTML and leads to broken JavaScript. Duplication of the `name` will break the jQuery Validate plugin because the `name` attribute is how it keeps track of the form fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code...

```
$(element).append('<li>' + error.text() + '</li>');
```

You would never need to include the HTML tags in this context; the plugin allows you to change the default `<span>` container into whatever you want by setting the `errorElement` option.  However, you still should not use an `<li>` container here because you'll end up with an `<li></li>` nested *inside* of an `<li></li>` and that's invalid HTML.

So just leave `errorPlacement` as the default; remove it.

Then set the `errorElement` option to `div`, which forces the error message element onto its own line.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    errorElement: 'div',
    rules: {
        // your rules
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/L1x2fraw/**

---

**NOTE**:  You cannot have four `type="text"` elements with the same `name` and `id`.  Duplication of `id` is invalid HTML and leads to broken JavaScript.  Duplication of the `name` will break the jQuery Validate plugin because the `name` attribute is how it keeps track of the form fields.

---

**EDIT**:

If you'd like another list item while preserving the proper HTML structure, you would use the jQuery `.parent()` method inside the `errorPlacement` option.  This line tells the plugin to put the error label's `li` after the `li` containing the `input` element.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    errorElement: 'li',  // <- put error inside an 'li' container
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        // insert the error message 'li' after the 'li' containing the input field
        error.insertAfter($(element).parent('li')); 
    },
    rules: {
        // your rules
    }
});
```

**Result**:

```
<ul>
    ....
    <li>
        <input type="text" name="foo" />
    </li>
    <li>This is the error message for "foo"</li>
    ....
</ul>
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/L1x2fraw/1/**

Comment: I changed the code after your recommendation and it is now better, of course - thank you! I still have the issue with placing just one error message below the  li element with four types. I should probably think of changing the HTML some how...

Comment: @sika, use jQuery to traverse the DOM and insert the `<li>` for the error label after the `<li>` containing the `input`.  See my edited answer.

Comment: This do work in the sense that it places the message below all inputs just as I asked - thank you!! One thing I also would like, but it is perhaps not absolutely necessary, is that only one message would show up even if all inputs are wrong, as oppose to now where there will be an error message for each input made wrong. Really grateful for your help!

Comment: @sika, I more than fully answered your original question.  Look at [the `groups` option in the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups) for how to group several error messages into one.

Comment: Definitely! Sorry, I was really tired yesterday and simply forgot to accept your answer. You've been great help, couldn't ask for more!